# Perforce installation in network folder for Windows

Tags: windows, perforce

I would like to install the Windows version of Perforce in a network location so that users can call p4 via:

```
\\somewhere\p4.exe -p server:1666 -c some_client_name sync
```

where "somewhere" is consistently mapped on all Windows machines. I tried to do this by installing locally, then copying p4.exe to `\\somewhere`.

On the computer where I installed locally, `\\somewhere\p4.exe` works just fine. But when I switch to another machine and try to run

```
\\somewhere\p4.exe -p server:1666 info
```

I get the following error:

```
Perforce client error
    Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
    TCP connect to server:1666 failed.
    A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup.
```

What does this error mean? I couldn't find any information in the documentation; I suspect I might need another file besides p4.exe. Indeed, when I install Perforce locally on the other machine, using the local p4.exe works, but `\\somewhere\p4.exe` still does not.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need any other files besides P4.exe.

The TCP connection error is probably because that other machine isn't able to translate "server" into an IP address.

Try using some of the Windows command line tools to diagnose this, as in:

```
nslookup server
```

or

```
ping server
```

Also, try changing your test to run:

```
\\somewhere\p4.exe -p NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:1666 info
```

where the "NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN" is the IP address of your server machine.

Comment: In my case, both `nslookup server` and `ping server` work. Using the address from nslookup and running `\\somewhere\p4.exe -p NNN.NNN.NNN.NNN:1666 info`, I get the same error.

I think I'll work around this by just scripting a network install instead of installing to a network location. Would love to hear any more thoughts though, for my own educational purposes.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm sorry that didn't help. I still think it's a network name lookup issue. Here's the Microsoft API that's generating that error: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520(v=vs.85).aspx Unfortunately it doesn't give many more clues.

Comment: Perhaps it is a security thing. This related question looks very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368877/net-proccess-failing-dns-lookup-with-windows-7

Comment: That's a pretty interesting. It sounds plausible, since the local installation works fine, just not the network binary. Thanks!